# Finding out the output path of a project after built by MSBuild

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I am working on my build server and have got MSBuild to build the entire solution successfully using the switch `/p:Configuration=Release`.

Now for some of the projects included in this solution, I'd like to get the path to the output file (a DLL in this case). I don't want to have to change the project itself to redirect the file to a known folder, instead I'd like to create a script that automatically find out where the file where generated.

Is there a setting to msbuild to write down this info? I know the information is all over the place in the console output of MSBuild but I guess it was meant to be human readable rather than to be parsed by a script.

I've also tried using the project file xml but I was faced by the fact that Visual Studio is hiding non-xml information in fields like `condition` field which I am not sure how to parse.

Comment: How about use the MSBuild macro of "OutDir"? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. These macros anywhere in a project's Property Pages dialog box where strings are accepted.

Comment: Where do you want this value? In a shell? Written to a file? In the msbuild process building the project?